# Facebook API: Can I simply read posts from wall without loging in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I need to fetch public posts of given type from a Facebook wall and I can't figure out the easiest way. Can I use the Facebook API for this without the need to login the user? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can fetch public post without login in `Facebok`. For get feeds of any user, you must need access token. Public feeds take any valid access token, application tokens can be used.
- Set your app up in Facebook and it will give you an app id and an API key. Get the profile id for the public page feed you want, and that's all you need.
- Just replace `PROFILE ID OR NAME` and `APPID` and `SECRETKEY` values in below URL and you would get your desired result in `JSON` from `Facebook`

  ```
  https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE ID OR NAME/feed?access_token=APPID|SECRETKEY
  ```

Comment: It does work! Thanks :) Is there any documentation on how to parametrize the fetches if I want to target specific posts only? If not, I can live with that JSON I got and filter it.

Comment: I dont know at moment.. I will try to find it.. Anyway if it works for you than you may accept and upvote answer :)

Comment: Sure thing :) Would appreciate if you post your findings. Thanks.

Comment: Sure..Will do it if i could get something

Comment: I've found it. The customization of the Graph API request is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api and can be fine tuned in the Graph Explorer. We can select only those relevant fields and even go to FQL. My reguest then looks like this: graph.facebook.com/PROFILE-ID-OR-NAME/feed?fields=message,description,caption,name&access_token=APPID|SECRETKEY

Answer (score 2):

If the posts are public you can scan them with a RSSReader. I wrote my own for this purpose.

This is how I get the Feed URL: http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Edit: If you’re fairly new to iOS development writing an RSSReader is an excellent exercise. You establish connections, parse strings, fill different data structures and probably create your first delegation protocol. If you’re in a hurry, take a look at these Github repositories: [SimpleRSSReader](https://github.com/dfreniche/SimpleRSSReader), [RSSReader](https://github.com/hmimthiaz/RSSReader)

A suggestion on how to approach this:

1. Read [this Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) about RSS. Facebook uses RSS 2.0, so take a closer look at the "RSS compared to Atom" section.
2. Create your RSSReader class (RSSEntry class) and create the data structure. (Compare to #1)
3. Established a connection to a very simple RSSFeed url (Use a simple blog). (The [AFNetworking Framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is worth a look)
4. Parse the input data and fill your data structures (Take a look at #1 for this)
5. When finished, call your delegate class and do something with your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please expand on the RSSReader, how do you approach this? I am on iOS.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. It's clear and valuable.