# Is it possible to get a facebook page info without authenticating by iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to show information about certain facebook pages in an **iOS app**, and I know for a fact that it is not needed any authentication when using the graph api by HTTP but I can't find a way to do it with the iOS SDK.  Is this possible or should I get it with the graph API??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API with just an appid and a key, no Facebook SDK required. See this: [Facebook API: Can I simply read posts from wall without loging in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702496/facebook-api-can-i-simply-read-posts-from-wall-without-loging-in)